# Use facet_grid option to plot column of dataframe with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, simulation, facet

I get some result from simulation, and i want to make a facetting like this diagram below, and i don't know if it's possible to make this with ggplot2 and the facet_grid option.

My result for simulations have this "simplified" form, one line by simulation :

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("P1 P2 P3 P4 R 
1 2e-5 1.0 0.6 3 1
2 4e-6 1.5 0.7 1.5 2
3 6e-7 1.2 0.6 2.5 3 
4 8e-8 1.45  0.65 3.2 4
"))
```

And here you can see the simplified graphic i want to produce with ggplot2 and facet_grid

[image: graphic image ggplot2]

I have one facet/graph by parameter, with different scale corresponding to min/max values for each of my parameter... You can also see on this graphic the color correspondance to localize each simulation in parameter space.

Thanks a lot for help

SR.

Comment: Aside from the small typo ("06" rather than "0.6") I don't think your data matches your intended graph. Is there an extra column or a missing column header? As it is, it looks like the data that goes with P1 is actually in the ID column.

Comment: Thanks, i correct the mistake. Graphics and data are for example, so data don't really represent the simplified figure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat.melt <- melt(data, id.vars='R')

ggplot(dat.melt, aes(x=0, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_point(aes(colour=factor(R))) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=1, scales='free') +
    coord_flip()
```

Plenty of other tweaks, but the gist is there.  Usually a good first step is to `melt` the data long and then start fiddling.  As a side note, its a good idea to avoid using `data` for a variable name since its a built in function.

Comment: Thanks, i have some problem to fix xscale with ggplot2 and facet option, so i post a new question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869540/overlapping-and-fixing-x-scales-in-facet-scale-free-in-order-to-make-a-film